# Cron perl script won't run

Tags: perl, cron, ubuntu-12.04

I'm trying to run a perl script on my Ubuntu server using cron. I have 3 perl scripts:

- **works.pl** (Works from the terminal. Works as a cron job)
- **fails.pl** (Works from the terminal. Fails as a cron job)
- **functions.pl** (all my shared functions are stored in here)

The only difference I can think of between 'works.pl' and 'fails.pl', is that 'fails.pl' uses the **require()** statement that references 'functions.pl'. 'Fails.pl' does not reference 'functions.pl'.

**Extra info**

- All of my perl scripts are located in the same folder, which is
  outside of my public folder.
- All of my perl scripts have the same permissions (740).

Any ideas? My user level is novice btw :-)

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`require` tries to find the script in one of the directories listed in the `@INC` array. This array usually contains the current directory, `.`. Therefore if your current directory is the one that `functions.pl` is located in then running `fails.pl` should work.

There are two ways to achieve this: First, change the directory before running the script, e.g. (cron entry example)

```
5 12 * * * cd /home/user/path/to/script ; ./fails.pl
```

Second, tell Perl where to find your script at compile time by putting this near the top of `fails.pl`:

```
BEGIN {
  unshift @INC, "/home/user/path/to/script";
};
```

Comment: I tried the 2nd method and it worked perfectly! Thanks for the answer and the explanation of how it works. Much appreciated :-)

Answer (score 0):

Moritz answer is great and true, but my `@INC` was already properly set; however, my situation is different. My perl program would run on the CLI and cron was *running* it but it would silently fail.

Turns out, I had:

```
my $width = `tput cols`; # breaks silently if run by CRON
```

In my script somewhere which only works on a terminal.  I changed it to:

```
my $width = 160; # cron likes this
```